# Unable to access Android SDK add-on list

Tags: android-studio

I'm new to Android programming. I was installing the `Android studio` and it got stuck at one point during installation showing the following message.

So, don't to how to proceed, I searched about it, but couldn't get explanation about this specific condition.

Can someone explain what to do next?

Screenshot:

[image]

Note: I'm using `Windows 7`, Installed `JDK 7` before installing Android studio.

Update: I tried to click upon "Setup Proxy" and then just clicked `ok` without doing anything and it worked, don't know how, but it did.

Try that if any one face the same.

Comment: Are you connected to internet, while installing?

Comment: @Der Golem Yes I'm connected to internet during installation ,should I stop the connection ?

Comment: @DerGolem Waiting for your reply !

Comment: No, you have to be connected.

Comment: We've had some "click on this" or "change this" answers, but can anyone explain what the message actually means?

Answer (score 26):

Add the following code to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\idea.properties

```
disable.android.first.run=true
```

Just open the file and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and type run then you will find this `run=false`, change it to true.

Comment: Thank you. Android Studio is now openning

Comment: For MAC OSX, right click androidstudio->Show Package->Contents->bin->idea.properties, then add the line in this answer.

Answer (score 7):

1) click on set up proxy.
2) Select option Auto Detect proxy.
3) Click continue, it will work!!
 All the best

Comment: It fixed my case. and I'm surprised it needs auto detect proxy

Answer (score 3):

I clicked `Cancel` at this screen and process of setup continued. I saw it on Linux after copying android studio folder from one PC to another. By the way, I started studio not connected to Internet cause I try to be able to work offline.

Answer (score 2):

I just hit this same problem - I was on a VPN. 
I tried setting a proxy with 'auto detect proxy settings' but it did not help.
Then I tried disconnecting from the VPN with no proxy set - this resolved the problem for me.
good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the right proxy to solve this problem. 
Set proxy ->
Manule...
Https   and  port

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes,if you use `Shadowsocks` on your macOS, maybe you will have the same problem.You can turn `Shadowsocks` off to deal with this problem.

[image]

Comment: Right. I set ShadowSocks properly to fix it as well.

Comment: @Lane Glad to help you!

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the problem by following the Steps:

1. Add the following code to "**C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\idea.properties**"
2. Open **idea.properties** with notepad
3. Then, enter the code below **anywhere** on a new line in the file (see attached image)

Code :

```
disable.android.first.run=true
```

4. Save the file
5. Run the application

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Clear your DNS if there is any dns server settings like google, comodo,
   symantec etc.
2. Check your firewall settings if you are using tinywall, zonealarm etc.

If your computer and network connection doesn't have any dns settings and firewall; then check your internet connection maybe there is an update process to slowing down your internet speed. So if there is a process stop or wait for it. And try again. Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

Yet another reason why this can happen is when your **time and date** settings are not synchronized correctly. I installed android studio inside a virtual machine linux guest that didn't properly synchronize the time with the windows host and as a consequence the above message occured even though my internet connection was working fine.