# First run of Android Studio. Unable to access Android SDK add-on list

Tags: android, android-studio, proxy

After trying to reinstall `Android Studio`, everything was fine until the first run.

While it was 'fetching Android SDK component information', it gave me an error saying:

`Unable to access Android SDK add-on list`

I clicked on Setup proxy, clicked on Auto-detect proxy settings, checked my connection (it said 'connection successful') then pressed `ok`. After that it just came up with the same error. No progress.

Any ideas on what I can do next?

I have no experience with proxy, so I only used Auto-detect proxy settings to stay simple.

PS. I've searched, but all I can find is to go behind the proxy, but I don't have the permissions to edit idea.properties.

**I'm using Windows 8.1 32 bit.**

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu or Windows?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1 32 bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access Android SDK add-on list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28918069/unable-to-access-android-sdk-add-on-list)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turn off your firewall, and check if it works perfectly, then add `android.bat` to trusted files in your windows firewall and restart firewall.

Comment: I cannot turn off my firewall. The link is there but it isn't clickable.

Comment: Ok I figured it out. Thanks for the answer, it helped me out a lot! Status: Answered.

Comment: I checked on windows firewall (allowed apps),and I noticed that "Private" and "Public" were not checked for "Android Studio" ,I checked both and it worked

Comment: Hi, I'm too stuck in the same process, what if I'm unable to turn off windows firewall (no admin access)??

Comment: If you cannot turn off firewall then go to "Windows firewall > Allow a program or feature through Windows Firewall > Allow another program > Select Android Studio > click ok"

Answer (score 24):

Rather than doing so many steps
click on set-proxy
click on auto set-proxy and then click on check box and then ok
you are done

Comment: @Rajan365 what did you finally do? I cannot turn off the firewall.

Comment: @bluepiranha Firewall seems like main culprit. When i did this at office machine it failed but it worked well in my personal laptop. You also can try adding firewall exception rule for AndroidStudio.exe, if you can't do anything with firewall

Comment: Click on manual proxy and set up your authentication details if you're behind a corporate proxy.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you must be connected to the internet.

1. Clear any DNS settings that might be present in your network adapter or router.
2. Either turn off the firewall (windows or antivirus's) completely or add an exception.
3. Stop any other application that might be using internet hence slowing it down.
4. Close android studio completely and run SDK Manager to update all the components that are awaiting an update, especially  addons.

Then run android studio.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue under **Ubuntu** 14.04.

I setup my proxy in the network config system (it is ok with internet browser).

I setup my proxy with environment variables http_proxy and https_proxy.

As I use 64 bit machine, I also did:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386

$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_80
```

Answer (score 1):

For the mac, you have to open dmg file as root, otherwise mac os does not allow android studio installer to connect to the internet.

```
sudo open ./android-studio-2022.3.1.19-mac_arm.dmg
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the following code to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\idea.properties

```
disable.android.first.run=false
```

to

```
disable.android.first.run=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable firewall exception like below to make SDK to get downloaded automatically:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Enviroment: Ubuntu 18.04, system Socks5 Proxy

Problem:
When I run the script `./studio.sh`, hit the same probem. The GUI and console show it is getting from `http://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml` but read times out.
Even if I set automatic find proxy in SDK Manager(I click "Checking Collection" and put above URI down, it shows success), it still doesn't work.

Solution

1. Bypass the Android SDK when running start up script.

- Edit the file `idea.properties` in installation folder: `{Path}/bin`
- Append a new line `disable.android.first.run=true`

2. Run `./studio.sh`. At this time you can open Android Studio, but when you click "new project", it will prompt: No Android SDK is available.
3. Install Android SDK. In SDK manager, go to `Android SDK` and install.
4. Disable the previous bypassing. Now AS can be opened suceesfully. All we need to do is undo the bypassing: `disable.android.first.run=true`

It seems that the system proxy works in the SDK manager, but not in the start up script.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me while using a VPN.

Pausing the VPN connection while going through the first run wizard solved the issue.

Answer (score -2):

for windows 7 i just check "No proxy" and continue. it works for me.