# Android Studio - First run - Unable to access Android SDK add-on list

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am on Macos installing Android studio with the bundle. In this machine, I have several Eclipse ADT installed. The initial run of Android Studio give me this error -  Unable to access Android SDK add-on list. I searched online and there is no solution works for me. 
I tried: 
1.Clear DNS
2.Turn off firewall 
3.Set proxy to Auto
4.I am in US right now

My Java is on 1.8.0_31. and interestingly I also have problem on updating my eclipse. It gives error: Unable to read repository at https://dl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml.
hostname in certificate didn't match:  !=  OR

So I am thinking about my networking setting problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28918069/unable-to-access-andriod-sdk-add-on-list

Comment: This one worked for me. For Mac the answer is in the comments.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31339245/3544773